# como abrir um arquivo json e popular em um jquery datatable?

Tags: javascript, json, jquery-datatables

Eu tenho um arquivo json gigantesco e queria abri-lo em um jquery datatable

**fiz um script que popula o arquivo .json em uma tabela do jquery datatable, mas o problema é que não está populando da maneira que gostaria:**
http://www.scarsphoto.com.br/teste/comparacao.html
Além disso, eu estou dando copy/paste e armazenando em uma array de objetos e mandando popular na tabela, desse jeito não está dando certo.

**esse é o script:**

```
        var json = [{
                "tempoNS" : 4251649,
                "tempoMS" : 4,
                "tamanhoArray" : 1999,
                "nome" : "Bubble iterativo"
            }, {
                "tempoNS" : 3064749,
                "tempoMS" : 3,
                "tamanhoArray" : 1999,
                "nome" : "Bubble recursivo"
            }, {
                "tempoNS" : 994920,
                "tempoMS" : 0,
                "tamanhoArray" : 1999,
                "nome" : "Insertion iterativo"
            }, {
                "tempoNS" : 908287,
                "tempoMS" : 0,
                "tamanhoArray" : 1999,
                "nome" : "Insertion recursivo"
            }, {
                "tempoNS" : 1500831,
                "tempoMS" : 1,
                "tamanhoArray" : 1999,
                "nome" : "Selection iterativo"
            }, {
                "tempoNS" : 1461891,
                "tempoMS" : 1,
                "tamanhoArray" : 1999,
                "nome" : "Selection recursivo"
            }, {
                "tempoNS" : 176888,
                "tempoMS" : 0,
                "tamanhoArray" : 1999,
                "nome" : "Merge iterativo"
            }, {
                "tempoNS" : 187754,
                "tempoMS" : 0,
                "tamanhoArray" : 1999,
                "nome" : "Merge recursivo"
            }, {
                "tempoNS" : 105348,
                "tempoMS" : 0,
                "tamanhoArray" : 1999,
                "nome" : "Quick recursivo"
            }, {
                "tempoNS" : 160588,
                "tempoMS" : 0,
                "tamanhoArray" : 1999,
                "nome" : "Heap recursivo"
            }, {
                "tempoNS" : 100217,
                "tempoMS" : 0,
                "tamanhoArray" : 1999,
                "nome" : "CombSort Sem Otimização"
            }
        ];
        var tamanhoJson = json.length;
        var results = "";

        for (var i = 0; i < tamanhoJson; i++) {
            results += "<tr>";
            results += "<td>" + json[i].tamanhoArray + " Elementos</td>";
            results += "<td>" + json[i].nome + " </td>";
            results += "<td>" + json[i].tempoNS + " ns</td>";
            results += "<td>" + json[i].tempoMS + " ms</td>";
            results += "</tr>";
        } 

        results += "<br />";
        var div = document.getElementById("example");
        console.log(results);
        div.innerHTML = results;
```

**se eu faço com os dados já populados no html, funciona:**
http://scarsphoto.com.br/teste/comparacao-com-dados-ja-populados-no-html

**esse é arquivo .json que gostaria de popular no datatable jquery:**
http://www.scarsphoto.com.br/teste/teste.json

*estou seguindo este exemplo:*
https://www.datatables.net/manual/styling/bootstrap-simple.html

qual a melhor maneira de se fazer, é via ajax?
desconheço tal procedimento, poderiam me falar como eu faço?

Comment: Seu Json está todo como objeto está correto isto? Faltou um [ no começo e outro no fim para você conseguir convertê-lo em uma lista de objetos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar o `$.getJSON` do jquery para obter os dados.

```
 var url = "http://www.scarsphoto.com.br/teste/teste.json";
            $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
                popularDataTables(data.d);
  });
```

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://www.scarsphoto.com.br/teste/teste.json. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:28026' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

Mais tem me gerado o seguinte erro que pode ser resolvido [Aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20433655/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-or).

Você não precisa percorrer todo o array para preencher a tabela, Veja que no final usei o `ID` da tabela colocando seu array na propriedade `aaData` do Jquery Datables, definindo quais seriam as colunas do corpo da tabela.

Coloque o código  dentro de uma função e passe os dados por parametro.

```
function popularDataTables(json){
    $('#example').DataTable({
                    "aaData": json,
                    "aoColumns": [
                        { "mDataProp": "tempoNS" },
                        { "mDataProp": "tempoMS" },
                        { "mDataProp": "tamanhoArray" },
                         { "mDataProp": "nome" }
                    ],
                });
}
```

Segue um exemplo que possa te ajudar.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>tempoNS</th>
                        <th>tempoMS</th>
                        <th>tamanhoArray</th>
                        <th>nome</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </form>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var json = [{
                "tempoNS": 4251649,
                "tempoMS": 4,
                "tamanhoArray": 1999,
                "nome": "Bubble iterativo"
            }, {
                "tempoNS": 3064749,
                "tempoMS": 3,
                "tamanhoArray": 1999,
                "nome": "Bubble recursivo"
            }, {
                "tempoNS": 994920,
                "tempoMS": 0,
                "tamanhoArray": 1999,
                "nome": "Insertion iterativo"
            }, {
                "tempoNS": 908287,
                "tempoMS": 0,
                "tamanhoArray": 1999,
                "nome": "Insertion recursivo"
            }, {
                "tempoNS": 1500831,
                "tempoMS": 1,
                "tamanhoArray": 1999,
                "nome": "Selection iterativo"
            }, {
                "tempoNS": 1461891,
                "tempoMS": 1,
                "tamanhoArray": 1999,
                "nome": "Selection recursivo"
            }, {
                "tempoNS": 176888,
                "tempoMS": 0,
                "tamanhoArray": 1999,
                "nome": "Merge iterativo"
            }, {
                "tempoNS": 187754,
                "tempoMS": 0,
                "tamanhoArray": 1999,
                "nome": "Merge recursivo"
            }, {
                "tempoNS": 105348,
                "tempoMS": 0,
                "tamanhoArray": 1999,
                "nome": "Quick recursivo"
            }, {
                "tempoNS": 160588,
                "tempoMS": 0,
                "tamanhoArray": 1999,
                "nome": "Heap recursivo"
            }, {
                "tempoNS": 100217,
                "tempoMS": 0,
                "tamanhoArray": 1999,
                "nome": "CombSort Sem Otimização"
            }
            ];
            $('#example').DataTable({
                "aaData": json,
                "aoColumns": [
                    { "mDataProp": "tempoNS" },
                    { "mDataProp": "tempoMS" },
                    { "mDataProp": "tamanhoArray" },
                     { "mDataProp": "nome" }
                ],
            });
        });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```